# Why is Code formatting broke and is wrong, not very helpful

Tags: google-apps-script, ide

If use Object.entries() or

`for (q of questions) { //etc }`

The code formatting wrong reports badly braces, with red ones in wrong places and messes up the indentation.

Comment: [mcve]..........

Comment: Possible duplicate [Why does google script editor stop paren matching after 100 lines in a function and does it affect the code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13711260/1595451)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, It is not recommended to use the official editor for code indent,highlighting, debugging or autocomplete as it is buggy in many ways.

In your case specifically, Both `Object.entries()` and `for...of` are V8 features. These features don't show up in autocomplete or have correct syntax highlighting.

Consider using [clasp](/questions/tagged/clasp) + [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript) to develop locally. Also, A new editor/ide based on Monaco is scheduled.